# Can Boost IPC survive the program crash and server crash?

Tags: c++, boost

I am Using Boost Message Queues to implement persistence Queues So I have the Following Doubts that I didn't find in the documentation.

Is it Good to use for Persistence?

Can it survive the program crash or system crash?

I want to store the structure objects in the queue How can achieve that.

Sorry for long listing...

Comment: The listing is so short I don't see any code :)

Comment: Actually Long listing of questions ?